# Is it reasonable to ask for a formal work contract and for the compensation I was promised?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I am a software developer at a small company, 4 people in total. When I started to work there, one and a half year ago approximately, I entered as a intern, with intern duties and an intern pay, as the time passed, I started to grow within the company, my duties and responsibilities started to grow as well, but the amount that I earn is almost the same, except for a raise that I got some months ago.
I made numerous projects for the company, started to learn Android programming from scratch and made a number of apps, of those, one is an app we offer to our clients that already have our desktop solution and ask for a considerable amount for it, the payment is monthly and when I made that app I was promised 50% of that money, the app is up and running in more than 40 devices and guess what: never saw a penny of it.
Within one year, my internship contract expired and I didn't made a new one, so, I don't have any bonds to the company whatsoever.
The big advantage of working there is that I don't have fixed hours, as my college's classes are all in the morning, I work only on the afternoon for 5 or 4 hours a day and still make the same amount. I can take pretty much any day off as long as I have a good reason to do so or leave early if needed (I've worked in other places before with fixed hours, and I know this isn't an easy task).

So, the big question is: should I demand/ask for a formal contract or something like that (and maybe a raise, since I am still making almost the same as when I started as a intern) and for the compensation I was promised for making the app in the first place? My boss is a real nice guy, I feel extremely free to do anything in  the office, new projects I come up with, discussing ideas, telling jokes, is a real nice place to work, I don't want to risk losing any perks for pushing things too far.

*Edit: I don't know if the background (country) is really important, but for the record: I'm uneasy about the formal arrangement and contracts of work because I know my boss is against bureaucracy and my country is world famous for it's bureaucracy, I'm in a comfortable position at the moment, I fear that demanding a formal arrangement from him could put me in a bad position, something along the lines that I'm not as comfortable with his word as I was before.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Is it just the pay and not getting anything from app-sales, or is there another reason you want a contract? (I mean; it's almost always good to have a contract, but we'd like to tailor the advice to the question and it's not entirely clear to me why you want the contract.)

Comment: You should ALWAYS have a formal contract in place. That will protect you against employers who promise bonuses / profit shares and then don't deliver.

Comment: Important information: When you say you haven't seen any money yet, have you *asked your boss about it?*. That is, have they explicitly told you that it's not going to happen, or have they simply forgotten about it.

Comment: Important Life Lesson: "Verbal contracts are only worth the paper they're written on"

Comment: "my internship contract expired and I didn't made a new one, so, I don't have any bonds to the company whatsoever" - If your contract expired and you don't have a new one that sounds to me like you are out of a job. Are you still working there in spite of this?

Comment: I really like working there, I enjoy what I do and the people that I work with, including my boss, who I consider to be a great friend, who helped me in situations that I needed and etcetera.

Comment: Voting to close because you are not asking a question you are asking for advice of a specific choice which is off-topic. Maybe you can rephrase to a specific question?

Comment: The question is in the title. Should or not ask for a formal contract of work and compensation for the work I did?

Comment: See, that is not an answerable question. We can´t tell you what to do!

Comment: Also, country does matter, because depending on the legal system there may be rules that apply, like minimum wage, income tax registration and black labor prevention laws etc. which may have an impact on your situation.

Comment: To follow up on Daniels comment in some country's it's is a statutory right to have your contract of employment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the big question is: should I demand/ask for a formal contract or
>   something like that (and maybe a raise, since I am still making almost
>   the same as when I started as a intern) and for the compensation I was
>   promised for making the app in the first place?

Ask for whatever you want. If you don't ask, you won't get.

You have to decide if the risk of asking equates to "pushing too far" or not. You'll have to decide that based on your knowledge of the company and manager.

And based on your comment of "guess what: never saw a penny of it" you have to decide if this is the kind of company you want to work for or not.

A raise seems extremely reasonable (I expect all interns to get more when they are signed on as permanent employees), payment for a past "promise" is a bit more iffy. You may have to have a long discussion about what that "promise" actually meant. Clearly, since you aren't receiving anything yet, there is a difference of opinion here.

You really aren't in a position to demand anything. You can threaten walking out if you don't get what you want. Only you are in a position to judge if this would be likely to be effective or not.

If you are granted anything, make sure you get it in writing this time, rather than just a "promise". That way, you'll avoid issues like the ones you are experiencing now.

Comment: +1 for `You really aren't in a position to demand anything`. The OP says they're on good terms with the boss, so making demands could jeopardise that. It would be a better idea to arrange a meeting with the boss to discuss the status of employment in a civil and calm manner, and take it from there.

Comment: Exactly. I can and will do that for the compensations part of the problem. I'm just uneasy about the formal arrangement of work and that stuff.

Comment: Just because you never got a payment from the promise does not necessarily mean the boss does not honor it. Did you ever ask and got denied the payment? Could just be that the boss thinks about yearly payment, or waiting for invoice etc.

Comment: @UnluckyFellow: Which is why I suggested you should have the meeting to discuss your employment status based on this: `"my internship contract expired and I didn't made a new one, so, I don't have any bonds to the company whatsoever"`. That way you can professionally bring attention to the promises that were made and discuss your future at that workplace; most importantly, getting an updated contract if you stay there.